# Convert Object Array To Array With Calculation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working with the following object array and attempting to convert it into an array:

```
const data = [
  {
    count: 3,
    userName: "Paul Crewe",
    value: "Activity Type",
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    userName: "Nate Scarborough",
    value: "Activity Type",
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    userName: "Nate Scarborough",
    value: "Another Activity Type",
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    userName: "Paul Crewe",
    value: "Another Activity Type",
  },
];
```

Expected Outcome:

```
const outcome = [
  ['userName', 'Paul Crewe', 'Nate Scarborough'],
  ['Activity Type', 3, 1],
  ['Another Activity Type', 1, 1]
];
```

The outcome array takes the data and uses the `userName` key to create to first array element followed by the format of `value`, `count` for each additional array element. For example,

```
['userName', 'Paul Crewe', 'Nate Scarborough'],
[{value}, {count for Paul Crewe}, {count for Nate Scarborough} ],
```

I feel that using a `reduce` is appropriate and have started with:

```
data.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.userName] = { value: c.value, count: c.count };
  a[c.userName].count += c.count;
  return a;
}, {});
```

But this results in an undesired outcome like:

```
{
  Nate Scarborough: {value: "Another Activity Type", count: 2},
  Paul Crewe: {value: "Another Activity Type", count: 2},
}
```

Comment: What’s the use of such a weird structure? Would it not make more sense to keep this as an object on the main level, have `userName`, `Activity Type` and `Another Activity Type` be properties of that object, and the values then would be the arrays (minus that first value) …?

Comment: The expected result array (`outcome` above) will be used to feed the required format of a data visualization library.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :-) Are these three properties static, or do you needs this for a variable number of properties or properties with unknown names as well? And the first array, is that just supposed to hold the user names in the order the appear in in the input data first?

Comment: Number of properties will be variable and with unknown names. Yes - this first array hold the user names in the order the appear in in the input data first.

Comment: And do you need the arrays in outcome to be in that specific order, or does that not matter (because the target application will infer that from the first value of each array)?

Comment: No particular array order other than the first array must be the `userName` entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the key `userName` and build new value rows as requires. It works with anrbitrary count of values.

This solution could return an array of sparse arrays. If not wanted, then you need to map the inner array with a default zero.

```js
const
    data = [{ count: 3, userName: "Paul Crewe", value: "Activity Type" }, { count: 1, userName: "Nate Scarborough", value: "Activity Type" }, { count: 1, userName: "Nate Scarborough", value: "Another Activity Type" }, { count: 1, userName: "Paul Crewe", value: "Another Activity Type" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var vIndex = r.findIndex(([v]) => v === o.value),
            index = r[0].indexOf(o[r[0][0]]);

        if (vIndex < 0) {
            vIndex += r.push([o.value]);
        }            
        if (index < 0) {
            index += r[0].push(o[r[0][0]]);             
        }
        r[vIndex][index] = (r[vIndex][index] || 0) + o.count;
        return r;
    }, [['userName']]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m a bit old-school when it comes to working with arrays - I am more comfortable with doing my own loops, than the various “fancy” array methods.

Here’s how I would handle this,

```js
const data = [
      {
        count: 3,
        userName: "Paul Crewe",
        value: "Activity Type",
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        userName: "Nate Scarborough",
        value: "Activity Type",
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        userName: "Nate Scarborough",
        value: "Another Activity Type",
      },
      {
        count: 1,
        userName: "Paul Crewe",
        value: "Another Activity Type",
      },
    ];
    
    const temp = {
      userName : []
    };
    
    data.forEach(function(e) {
      // push username only if not in array already
      if(temp.userName.indexOf(e.userName) === -1) {
        temp.userName.push(e.userName);
      }
      // create empty array for activity name, if not exists yet
      if(!temp[e.value]) {
        temp[e.value] = [];
      }
      temp[e.value].push(e.count)
    });
    
    var outcome = [];
    // special treatment for userName, to make sure that comes first
    temp.userName.unshift('userName');
    outcome.push(temp.userName);
    
    for(k in temp) {
      if(k != 'userName') {
        temp[k].unshift(k); // insert activity name at front of array
        outcome.push( temp[k]); // insert array into final result array
      }
    }
    console.log(outcome)
```

Using the `temp` helper object makes it easier to access the correct array using the activity name - if I went with the desired structure directly, that would mean looping over the arrays and comparing the first entry all the time to find the right one, whereas with an object a simple property lookup will do.